# Android Studio 3.1 does not render an XML file due to a Java class missing

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

It always shows me this error in the massages:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener

My project is literally [Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) and I just open Android Studio and click on the empty activity and then wait for the build to finish, but it doesn't render the app.

I reinstalled Android Studio and JDK 10. But it doesn't work. The project shows fine in virtual device and I can even edit Hello, World! to any string, but in the XML view, it just shows a white screen:

[image: Screenshot of project Hello, World!].

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:180)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:61)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:118)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(ActionBarContainer.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:481)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:264)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:222)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:209)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:337)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:348)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:248)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.BridgeActionBar.<init>(BridgeActionBar.java:89)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.AppCompatActionBar.<init>(AppCompatActionBar.java:68)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createActionBar(Layout.java:277)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:161)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:288)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:544)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:678)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, it happens. You can fix it easily.

The first method:

Open build.gradle (Module: app) under Gradle Scripts and change version alpha3 to **alpha1** and Sync now

> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

The second method:

Open file *style.xml* under *res* → *values* → *style.xml* and change this line:

```
style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Put `Base.` before Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar like

```
style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: wow Thank you, ur a miracle, used the first method and it worked. really thank you

Comment: This issue exists in `28.0.0-rc02` too and I want to use `NoActionBar` and not `DarkActionBar`.

Comment: Change the version isn't a good solution, i had the same problem with v7:28.0.0-rc02 and v7:28.0.0-rc01, The definitive solution is change the parent "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" with "Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" in the style you use it in res/values/styles.xml

Comment: This problem still remains. version: 28.0.0-rc02

Comment: and final version as well :-(

Answer (score 3):

#### - Use Alpha/Beta at your own risk

- You are developing an app, so you don't want to face these types of issues. So I suggest you always use the stable version of every dependency.

The issue you faced was due to using an alpha version of the **AppCompat** library. Use the stable version to get rid of this issue now and in the future.

#### 1. Use the `android.support` stable version

Currently 27.1.1 is the latest version of AppComactV7. You can see the **[Maven Repo link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7?repo=google)** to find out the latest.

```
final def SUPPORT_VERSION = "27.1.1"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_VERSION"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_VERSION" // use only if already using
```

I use definitions to have the same version for all support versions. Also ignore the design library if you are not already using it.

#### 2. Downgrade `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` (optional)

You also need to downgrade your **`compileSdkVersion`** and **`targetSdkVersion`** to remove some Gradle warnings.

So use the below versions.

```
compileSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 27
```

Read about [Alpha and Beta releases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40147499/6891563).

Comment: It is true. Until the stable version we should wait!

Answer (score 2):

Go to
Gradle scripts>build.gradle(module app) > change 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3' to 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

You may have something other than alpha3 after "-v7:28.0.0-" whatever it is just change it to alpha1.

Comment: don't forget to sync project with gradle build after

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it easily.

Open build.gradle(Module: app) under Gradle Scripts and update the version of appcompat to given below and Sync now

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

and of course

```
compileSdkVersion 27
```

Until version 28 full ver comes!

Comment: Change the version isn't a good solution, i had the same problem with v7:28.0.0-rc02