# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener

Tags: android, event-listener

When I try to add the image view to the layout editor of Android Studio it is not showing up and also it is showing some errors

[image: this is the error showing in the android studio]

> Java

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:180)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:61)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:118)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.isLayoutRtlCompat(GridLayout.java:679)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.onLayout_Original(GridLayout.java:1082)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.onLayout(GridLayout.java)
    at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:19659)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19645)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout_Original(ConstraintLayout.java:1858)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java)
    at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:19659)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19645)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:19659)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19645)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
    at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:19659)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19645)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:346)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:544)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:678)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It is showing UnhandledKeyEventListener error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238779/android-studios-3-1-does-not-render-xml-file-due-to-java-class-missing click on above link, you will get idea

Comment: It still exists and the old post suggests reverting to the alpha version when we are in release candidate phase.

Comment: What are u trying to say Sudhir Khanger

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme In Android Studio 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50856622/failed-to-find-style-coordinatorlayoutstyle-in-current-theme-in-android-studio)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android/view/view$onUnhandledKeyEventListener (onMeasure error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51305964/android-view-viewonunhandledkeyeventlistener-onmeasure-error)

Answer (score 3):

Make the changes in your **build.gradle (app level)** to downgrade to version 27 as below. Then sync and build project. Hopefully it will fix the issue..

**compileSdkVersion 27**

**targetSdkVersion 27**

**implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'**

Answer (score 1):

Open style.xml under res -> values -> style.xml and change this line

style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

put Base. before Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar like

style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Hope problem will be solved.